# How can I parse my active range in Google Sheets no matter what the size is?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have created a script that pulls information from my Google Sheets and then takes apart the structure of it so that I can format it into an eye-appealing box of text for Slack.  I have six columns in my sheet which I want to turn into a three-line box.

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange(); 
  var changeRange = 
  sheet.getRange(activeRange.getRow(),1,1,sheet.getLastColumn());
  changeRange.setBackgroundRGB(255, 255, 255);

  var values = activeRange.getValues();


  var output = {
    "text": JSON.stringify(values)}


  var str = values[0][0] + " | " + values[0][1] + "\nItem: " + values[0][2] + " | " + values[0][3] + "\nShorted: " + values[0][4] + "\nResolution: " + values[0][5] + "\n";
```

Then more stuff about posting it to Slack, but I didn't think that was important to include here.

My issue is that I can only highlight one line at a time with this format.  When I try to highlight multiple lines, it only reads the first one because my STR variable is only pulling six cells at a time.
If I add an additional line, as in:

var str = values[0][0] + " | " + values[0][1] + "\nItem: " + values[0][2] + " | " + values[0][3] + "\nShorted: " + values[0][4] + "\nResolution: " + values[0][5] + "\n";
var str = values[1][0] + " | " + values[1][1] + "\nItem: " + values[1][2] + " | " + values[1][3] + "\nShorted: " + values[1][4] + "\nResolution: " + values[1][5] + "\n";

It will only work for two lines, and sending one line will break it.  **How can I make sure that this will send out the same format for every single line even if I were to send up to one hundred lines?**  I currently have some other code in there that changes the background color of the lines that I select, and that seems to work no matter how many lines I select.

Comment: check the js for loop, you can loop over all the lines https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Comment: So I am trying to do this loop, but I want to know how to determine exactly how many rows are actually highlighted in Apps Script.  If I set it for a maximum number, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You can get the current number of rows with `values.length`

Comment: Thanks!  So here's what I have now, but it still doesn't seem to pick up more than just the first line.  
 

 {var i;
    for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) 
      var str = values[i][0] + " | " + values[i][1] + "\nItem: " + values[i][2] + " | " + values[i][3] + "\nShorted: " + values[i][4] + "\nResolution: " + values[i][5] + "\n";  }

Comment: Okay, further update: Here's what happens now.  It will only present the last line but not all of the highlighted lines.

Comment: try using `var str +=` instead of `var str =`, right now you change the value of str for every line instead of adding at the end of it :)

Comment: So I tried putting that plus sign in there and now the code is broken.  Does Google Apps Script not handle += the same as other codes?

Comment: It should handle it, since it's Js, if it doesn't you could just use `str = str + ` instead. The error message will be able to help you more than me

Comment: Hi!  Okay this works except that the very first part of it just throws out the word "undefined" and then it gives me the result i want.  How do I get rid of the undefined?

Comment: You may want to initialise str to a empty string before the loop.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what that means as far as what to write in the code.

Comment: I want to help you, but I can't code for you. Initialising is a basic concept in programming, you can look it up and learn from it more than if I just tell you what to write.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it to work!  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Liora, I am new to this website and I am trying to figure out how to give you props or gold or however it works on here.  How do I do it?

Comment: Hum well since I didn't add an answer to the question, there's no way for you to "reward" me. For your future questions, people might add answers and then you'll be able to upvote and check the answers, but right now you don't have anything to do.